# Why does waiting for `clock` value to change by 5,000 units not result in a delay of five seconds?

Tags: c

So I am having 2 global variables assigned value with `time(NULL)` value. Now after 5 sec, I want to have my previous Time value remain unchanged and only current Time value gets modified. I want to display the time duration. So I have written the code but not getting the right result. On one compiler (DevC++) I get the proper result as `timDrn == 5` but with an online compiler I get both variables at the same value and `timDrn == 0`. So am I going right or wrong? I want `prevTim` to remain unchanged and `curTim` value to be increased by 5 with `timeDrn = 5`.

My results with a local compiler (DevC++)

```
prevTim = 1585569873

curTim = 1585569873

prevTim = 1585569873

curTim = 1585569878

time duration = 5
```

My results with an online compiler

```
prevTim = 1585569915                                                                                                          

curTim = 1585569915                                                                                                           

prevTim = 1585569915                                                                                                          

curTim = 1585569915                                                                                                           

time duration = 0
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int prevTim ;
int curTim;
void delay(int number_of_seconds) 
{ 
    // Converting time into milli_seconds 
    int milli_seconds = 1000 * number_of_seconds; 

    // Storing start time 
    clock_t start_time = clock(); 

    // looping till required time is not achieved 
    while (clock() < start_time + milli_seconds) 
        ; 
} 
int main(void)
{
    int itr ,timDrn ;
    prevTim =time(NULL);
    curTim = prevTim; 

    printf("prevTim = %d \n",prevTim);  
    printf("curTim = %d \n",curTim);

    for(itr = 0 ;itr < 5 ;itr ++)
    {
        delay(1); //1 sec delay function
        curTim =time(NULL);
    }   

    timDrn =curTim - prevTim ;

    printf("prevTim = %d \n",prevTim);  
    printf("curTim = %d \n",curTim);
    printf("time duration = %d \n",timDrn);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Am I doing it right or wrong" - does it work for you?

Comment: @nicomp I want 1st result i.e. prevTim remains unchanged and curTim value to increased by 5 with timeDrn =5 .Bt I think that as prevTim is assigned with time(Null) , while solving for timDrn expression, prevTim will take current value of time(NULL) only. so result is 0.

Comment: So you answered your own question I think: you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @nicomp ok .fine.  so i tried making prevTim variable as const (const int prevTim ) bt it will be again wrong as its assigned with varing function time(NULL). So is there any other option ?

Comment: what is the value assigned to, for example, `prevTim` (both on your computer and on online compiler)? Is it `-1` (or some conversion thereof), perhaps?

Comment: @pmg I want to declare both variable as global.  there will be function (say here main())where one event/process will be there . So at  the start of event both variable will have same value (time(NULL) i.e. calender time in sec) and when event  gets completed ,only curTim will be changed

Comment: if the value yielded by `time(0)` is `(time_t)-1` it means the functionality of `time()` is not available in that implementation.

Comment: @pmg there is no issue in time()  .it is giving correct time .

Comment: Please post the **exact** output you get from both your local run and the online compiler run.  Your descriptions of the output are unclear.

Comment: @dbush added in quest pls see now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the online compiler, the time at the end of the program is the same as when it started. So I guess your `delay` function probably returns immediately to avoid people putting very long delays and having their program run for ever on the website. Trust your local compiler. An online compiler is for convenience and basic testing, not for real work.

Also, `delay` doesn't exist in `time.h`, so I wonder how this compiles. Usually, one uses `sleep`.

Comment: @user3559780: It may not be working as you expect, but since you didn't show it, how are we to know?

Comment: @user3559780: Having other code that is part of the troublesome program that you do not show in the question is a mistake. It prevents other people from analyzing the program. Post **all** relevant code. When asking for debugging help, provide a [mre].

Comment: This isn't an answer. Should be a comment.

Comment: @liberforce while solving  the " timDrn =curTim - prevTim ;" expression ,how local compiler took value of "prevTim" which  was 5 seconds earlier one?

Comment: @user3559780: So how did the compiler took that value? You never change `prevtime` after your initial `prevTim =time(NULL);`, so it remains the same. And when you do `curTim =time(NULL);`, you overwrite `curTim`, so it changes each second.

Comment: BTW, your `delay` function is useless (and nocive, as it eats all the CPU), use `sleep` from `time.h` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `delay` function incorrectly assumes `clock` returns time in milliseconds. The C standard does not specify this. Per C 2018 7.27.2.1 3:

> To determine the time in seconds, the value returned by the `clock` function should be divided by the value of the macro `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

Delaying a program in this way is wasteful because it consumes processor time and is disrespectful in a submission to an online compiler. Although there is no standard C function to suspend program execution for a time, many systems provide a `sleep` function that will. (This is not wasteful because it requests the operating system to suspend program execution, so the processor can do other work or go into a low-power state.)

Comment: ok fine. let us say we calculated the delay properly  but my doubt is 
 that while solving the " timDrn =curTim - prevTim ;" expression ,how local compiler took value of "prevTim" which was 5 seconds earlier one?